# Is there a way to stop 401 unauthorized from logging to console?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a function in Vue.js which sends data to the back-end to log the user in. However in cases where the User doesnt exist it returns an 401 unauthorized. That is ok by me , the problem is that it always seems to be logged into the console. I already know i can handle it but it always logs to the console. Is there a way to stop the web console from logging the 401 unauthorized ?

My function

```
  this.$store
          .dispatch("userLogin", {
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password,
          })
          .then((response) => {
            switch (response.status) {
              case 401:
                //I know unauthorized attempt can be handled here.
                break;
            }
            this.$router.push({ name: "Admin" });
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.response.data);
          });
      }
```

I want to stop this from being logged.

https://ibb.co/6vNdYrw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that. It's the same as trying to stop requests from showing up in Chrome's Network  Tab. It's implemented by the browser and the website does not have control over it.

Comment: But is it safe for others to see this request ? Isnt there a security issue with this ?

Comment: @user655941 - The person who is trying to authenticate is the person using the browser. You can't hide information from them.

Comment: @user655941 you need to assume that the user can see ANYTHING that is sent in a request-response because it will always end up on their machine, logged or not its visible.

Comment: Even google.com's requests can be seen in their network tab

Comment: Thank you guys i thought that this was smth that could be handled.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really block logging responses from requests into browser console.

In your case you have such a flow, that server responds with code 401 when you are sending invalid user details. It should obviously respond with 404 but probably you do not have any control over it.

The solution to this could be to have function, that would evaluate both `response.status` and `response.data` and based on response.data process your case further.

Some initial solution:

```
switch (response.data && response.status) {
  case ('not found' && 401):
    // handle case
    break;

  default:
    break;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you , i already knew how to handle the case i just didnt want it to log.